# Operator < is undefined for argument Number, int

Tags: java, generics

Am I trying to be too clever here?

```
  private static <T extends Number> Long extractLong(T value) {
    if ( value < Long.MIN_VALUE || value > Long.MAX_VALUE ) {   // <= compile error
      throw new NumberFormatException("Conversion from " + value + " to Long will overflow");
    }
    return value.longValue();
  }
```

which yields the compile error:

> The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) T, long

But if I do the function explicitly it compiles :

```
  private static Long extractLong(Long value) {
    if ( value < Long.MIN_VALUE || value > Long.MAX_VALUE ) {
      throw new NumberFormatException("Conversion from " + value + " to Long will overflow");
    }
    return value.longValue();
  }
```

Comment: `Number` does not implement `Comparable`, so you can not compare. `Comparable` is implemented by the classes `Long` `Double` etc... Try implementing `Comparable<Number>` in T

Comment: Correction: `Number` is not `Comparable`... could try `toLongValue` though. Reason it does not work is just <, +, etc. is defined only for primitives. For Long, autounboxing works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Java does not support operator overloading, it is not possible to define the meaning of the comparison operators `<` and `>` for any type of objects. Or in other words:

```
Number a = new Long(1);
Number b = new Long(2);
if (a < b) // does NOT compile - objects cannot be compared using `<` or `>`!
```

The reason why your second example compiles is [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The `Long` objects are automatically converted to `long` values which are of course comparable as you did. But as there is no generic autoboxing for objects of type `Number`, this does not work in the first case.

So how can we check for overflow then? The simplest way I think is to check the `double` value first:

```
private static long extractLong(Number value) {
    double v = value.doubleValue();
    if (v < Long.MIN_VALUE || v > Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new NumberFormatException(...);
    }
    return value.longValue();
}
```

Note that this does not cover the case where `value` is a very large `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` that cannot be expressed as `double` either. Therefore you'd need to do `instanceof` checks too.

**Warning:** This test using `doubleValue()` does not work when `value` is slightly larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` (or slightly smaller than `Long.MIN_VALUE`). The reason is that due to the nature of floating point values, conversion from integral or decimal numbers to `double` is not exact. More concrete, all values from `Long.MAX_VALUE - 511` to `Long.MAX_VALUE + 1025` will be converted to one and the same double value (`9.223372036854776E18`). Example:

```
double d1 = Long.MAX_VALUE - 511;
double d2 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
double d3 = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).add(BigInteger.valueOf(1025)).doubleValue();
// d1 == d2 == d3 due to lack of precision of double!
```

But this means, that the above expression `v > Long.MAX_VALUE` will be `false` for all those values although some of them are effectively larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`:

```
long l = extractLong(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).add(BigInteger.ONE));
// l is now -9223372036854775808 => overflow check failed!
```

---

Side note: It is not necessary to use generics here! Just use `Number` directly instead of `T` and you can pass all kinds of numbers. Thanks to polymorphism, this works since Java 1.0... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Basically the T here could be treated as an implementation of abstract class `java.lang.Number`. And `Number` does not support any of the arithemetic or logic operator like `+, -, <, >, <=` etc. as Java does not support operator overloading. However the out-of-box implementation class like `Integer, Long, Double` etc would work with these operators as they are being auto-boxed to `int, long, double` etc. In your case when you say the type as `T` the compiler cannot determine what implementation it would use until runtime. It can be an implementation which doesn't support auto-boxing. So compiler shown error.

But when you change the argument type to `Long` the compiler know for sure that this could be auto-boxed an the operator could be applied. So no error. As a solution if you could use like

```
private static <T extends Number> Long extractLong(T value) {

    if ( value.doubleValue() < Long.MIN_VALUE || value.doubleValue() > Long.MAX_VALUE ) {   
      throw new NumberFormatException("Conversion from " + value + " to Long will overflow");
    }
    return value.longValue();
}
```

Comment: Won't work as `value.longValue()` will return a `long` value which is - of course - always within the valid range of a `long` value (`[Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE]`), hence the overflow detection will not work.

Comment: Good thought. My idea was just to give a hint on how this could be achieved with argument as T. He could use `value.doubleValue()` may be. :)

Answer (score 2):

Only numeric types can be compared using the ordering operators in Java. T can be not numeric, so compiler doesn't allow this. Use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare objects.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a type argument T which extends Number class,then T represents a class which extends Number class.Please note that  comparison operators can only be used for primitives,not for classes (unless it is wrapped to its corresponding class,say int is wrapped to Integer).Since,the compiler cannot ascertain whether you are using a wrapper class(Long,Integer,Double,Float etc) or a user defined class which extends Number ,it gives compile time error.
Example:-

```
class MyNumber extends Number{
}
```

Objects of  MyNumber class do not understand > operator.Please use a comparator for comparing Objects.

Answer (score 1):

`> < >= <=` are not defined for your Type `T`. They are defined for the primitve types `int`, `long`, `float` `double` and as a special for their wrapper types `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`. you need to inherrit from interface comparable and use the method `compareTo` after you implemented how to compare your Types.